# How do I populate custom field with current user role in Woocommerce

Tags: php

I am trying to populate a custom field called Customer Type in checkout with the current user role.  I tried the below in my functions.php of my child theme and thought it would work but it does nothing.  Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
function onboarding_update_fields( $fields = array() ) {

   $fields['customertype'] = $user;

   return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'onboarding_update_fields' );
```

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugins are off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their communities.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_current_user()` returns a user object. You can't output objects directly.

Proceed by getting the users roles like `$roles = (array)$user->roles;`. Note that this returns an array though, so you will probably want to use the first element with `$roles[0]`.

Your code might look like this (untested):

```
function onboarding_update_fields( $fields = array() ) {
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
   $roles = (array)$user->roles;
   $fields['customertype'] = $roles[0];
   return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'onboarding_update_fields' );
```

Additionaly, you might want to check if the user is logged in, otherwise there might not be a user and role available.

WordPress Code Reference articles: [wp_get_current_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/), [User object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/).